# How to set resource which is not mapped

Tags: zend-framework, autoload

The dir structure is:

```
application
    models
       Milestones
          ObserverBroker.php    => Application_Model_Milestone_ObserverBroker
       Observers
          Milestone.php         => Application_Model_Observer_Milestone
```

at Bootstrap.php

```
$loader->addResourceType('observer','models/observers','Model_Observer');
$loader->addResourceType('observerbroker','models/milestones','Model_Milestone');
```

The problem I encountered was:

```
[f@gail]$ php zfrun.php \
>         --environment development -a task.create-milestone -m '%s' \
>         -p '%s'
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Application_Model_Milestone_ObserverBroker' not found in /var/www/html/sites/plugin_handler/application/controllers/TaskController.php on line 55

Fatal error: Class 'Application_Model_Milestone_ObserverBroker' not found in /var/www/html/sites/plugin_handler/application/controllers/TaskController.php on line 55


[f@gail]$ php zfrun.php \
>         --environment development -a task.update-milestone -m '%s' -o '%s' \
>         -p '%s'
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Application_Model_Milestone_ObserverBroker' not found in /var/www/html/sites/plugin_handler/application/controllers/TaskController.php on line 81
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have to add a resource type for classes in the `Application_Model_` namespace.

The default module autoloader already includes rules for this, provided your configured `appnamespace` is "Application"

As a test, I just created two models, `Application_Model_Test` (application/models/Test.php) and `Application_Model_Test_Test` (application/models/Test/Test.php) and without adding anything further, was able to create an instance of each in my controller.

**Edit**

On re-reading your question, it looks like you want to store the `Application_Model_Milestone_` classes in "Milestone*s*" (plural) and likewise for the Observer classes. Whilst I think you would be better off just storing these under `application/models/Milestone` and `application/models/Observer` and letting the default autoloader do its thing, it looks like your problem is due to case sensitivity.

Your `$loader->addResourceType()` calls are using lowercase folder names whereas your directory structure example uses `Milestones` and `Observers` (capital first letters).

This will fail on a case-sensitive filesystem.

Comment: I have changed the directory Milestones to Milestone and the Observers to Observer. Thank you for the answers. I use this one to implement observer pattern on a trac plugin.